# react adding new array method to return array's object item by it's key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some enum objects and i want to get its lebel by it's value.

Let's say this is my enum list

```
const enumList = {
    businessType: [
        { value: "b", label: "B2B" },
        { value: "s", label: "SAAS" },
        { value: "c", label: "C2C" },
    ],
    userType: [
        { value: "A", label: "Admin" },
        { value: "s", label: "Super User" },
        { value: "t", label: "trainer" },
    ]
}
```

So now I want to get a particular object `label` by its key.

like this,

```
enumList.userType.getLabel('s')'
// super user
```

I mean, i want to make it re-usable, currently i am doing like this and i dont like it

```
index = enumList.userType.findIndex(x => x.value ==="s");
enumList.userType[index].label
// super user
```

Does anyone know how can i make it re-usable to access it from globally like this `enumList.userType.getLabel('s)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This custom Array method will allow you to do this `enumList.userType.getLabel('s')` and receive `'Super User'`

```
Array.prototype.getLabel = function(val) {
  return this.find(({value}) => value === val).label
}
```

Comment: Brother, i need array prototype method to access it globally

Comment: edited my answer to use a custom Array method to be used as you specified in the question

Comment: the updated one works well, thanks for you help

Comment: This is a bad answer. See [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)

Comment: This is the answer being asked for specifically, not necessarily the best way to do it. In comments above, it was clarified that they wanted an Array prototype method.

Comment: `This is the answer being asked for specifically` -  [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 0):

See [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)

It looks like you want a one-liner, so just use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
const { label } = enumList.userType.find(userType => userType.value === 's');
```